# Apocalypse doesn't happen for some reason

Tags: science-based, apocalypse

What would be a realistic apocalyptic event that was confirmed by most all scientists and experts, but that, for some reason, did not occur. I feel like an asteroid or meteor would be easily confirmed that it's trajectory was not impacting the planet. I want everyone preparing for the unavoidable and confirmed end of the world, but for some reason it doesn't happen.

**Qualifications:**

- This is an extinction level event
- All the world's scientists have agreed that this event is going to happen
- It is going to happen in a relatively short amount of time, < one year
- Not caused by aliens
- In the end, the event does not happen for a reason unforeseen by anyone

Comment: For asteroids, there are probabilities of impact, and there are scenarios when these probabilities are far from certain until the very end. Basically, we expect to be shot, but there is always a chance that the bullet will miss.

Comment: Idea generation question is off topic, because it attracts primarily opinion-based and low quality answers. All answers will be right and no way to judge the rightness of the answers.

Comment: It seems like this could benefit from some qualifications: something like "I need an apocalypse which certainly would kill off the majority of people, but provides X or Y situation, or has Z attributes."

Comment: Well, at least two humans escaped the Vogon constructor fleet.  With how long they had the plans on display, I think I'd call that an unavoidable and confirmed end of the world.

Comment: I think its a rather sad failure of a question when the answer is literally in the question.

Comment: @LaurenWheels33 Whoa, hold the phone... are you **explicitly** asking for a Deus Ex Machina?

Comment: Ha! Actually, yes, yes I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A meteor that becomes a comet**

A great idea is to have a meteor. It could be on a dead collision course to earth.  Last minute as it gets closer it could have ice on it.  The ice would begin to melt as it's exposed to the sun and eventually boil. Like a propulsion engine this could create a course correction sufficient enough for the meteor to completely harmlessly pass the planet